# Is it possible to use custom fonts in Mobile Safari?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, font

I need to install a font in iPad2, and Safari must be able to use it. Is it possible?

Solution:

I'm developing a iPad2 app using a web wrapper (PhoneGap) and a JS framework (Sencha Touch 2). I need to use custom fonts, for that I need to convert my TTF file (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and link the stylesheet.

Comment: The "solution" doesn't really install a font on the iPad, it just makes sure that the web app has access to it and displays it in Safari correctly. Good if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot install fonts on any iOS device without jail breaking or by creating an app.

But Safari can itself display fonts placed on a server with appropriate html code in the page.

Comment: I solved it, posting in a sec.

Answer (score -1):

As I'm developing a web app, I've converted the TTF file [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and linked the generated font file from my CSS stylesheet.

Comment: For the benefit of readers, why not explain in more detail what you did to get your font to display on Safari on your iPad.